# In shell, how do I delete numbered duplicate files?

Tags: bash, awk

I've got a directory with a few thousand files in it, named things like:

```
filename.ext
filename (1).ext
filename (2).ext
otherfile.ext
otherfile (1).ext
etc.
```

Most of the files with bracketed numbers are duplicates of the original, but in some cases they're not.

How can I keep my original files, delete the duplicates, but not lose the files that are different?

I know that I could `rm *\).ext`, but that obviously doesn't make sure that files match the original.

I'm using OS X, so I have a `md5` program that functions sort of like `md5sum` in Linux, though it puts the hash at the end of the line instead of the beginning.  I was thinking I could use an awk script to take the output of `md5 *.ext | awk 'some script'`, find duplicates by md5, and delete them, but the command line is too long (`bash: /sbin/md5: Argument list too long`).

And I don't know what to write in the script.  I was thinking of storing things in an array with this:

```
awk '{a[$NF]++} a[$NF]>1{sub(/).*/,""); sub(/.*(/,""); system("rm " $0);}'
```

But that always seems to delete my original.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I do it right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your awk script deletes original files because when you sort your files, `.` (period) sorts after  (space).  SO the first file that's seen is numbered, not the original, and subsequent checks (including the one against the original) compare files to the first numbered one.

Not only does `rm *\).txt` fail to match the original, it loses files that may not have an original in the first place.

I wouldn't do this quite this way.  Rather than checking *every numbered file* and verifying whether it matches an original, you can go through your list of originals, then delete the numbered files that match them.

Instead:

```
$ for file in *[^\)].txt; do echo "-- Found: $file"; rm -v $(basename "$file" .txt)\ \(*\).txt; done
```

You can expand this to check MD5's along the way.  But it's more code, so I'll break it into multiple lines, in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob              # Show nothing if a fileglob matches no files

for file in *[^\)].ext; do
  md5=$(md5 -q "$file")        # The -q option gives you only the message digest
  echo "-- Found: $file ($md5)"
  for duplicate in $(basename "$file" .ext)\ \(*\).ext; do
     if [[ "$md5" = "$(md5 -q "$duplicate")" ]]; then
        rm -v "$duplicate"
     fi
  done
done
```

As an alternative, you can probably get away with doing this a little more simply, with less CPU overhead than calculating MD5 digests.  Unix and Linux have a shell tool called [`cmp`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cmp), which is like `diff` without the output.  So:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for file in *[^\)].ext; do
  for duplicate in $(basename "$file" .ext)\ \(*\).ext; do
    if cmp "$file" "$duplicate"; then
      rm -v "$file"
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Thanks.  Great explanation and very educational.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use AWK, you could maybe do something simpler in bash:

```
for file in *\([0-9]*\)*; do
    [ -e "$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/ ([0-9]\+)//')" ] && rm "$file"
done
```

Hope this helps a little =)

Comment: This suffers from the classic [Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem.  Why do you want to grep the output of `ls`?  Why not simply use `for file in *\([0-9]\)*; do` ?  Also, your suggestion doesn't answer the OP's request to have "duplicate" files compared against the original using MD5 digests.

Comment: This example might as well be written with xargs - it can't tell of `X (2).jpg` duplicates `X (1).jpg` (perhaps `X.jpg` and `X (1).jpg` where deleted or never existed?) I recommend using MD5 on the contents and treating the filenames as artifacts, but ..

Comment: You don't need the `echo`. Use a here-string instead i.e. `sed -e 's/\s([0-9]\+)//' <<< "$file"`

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how would you write it with xargs? I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks! =)

Comment: This sed script doesn't work for me.  I tried: `echo "file (1).ext" | sed -e 's/\s([0-9]\+)//'`.  It just returns the original text.

Comment: That same line worked here =S. Perhaps you could try `echo "file (1).ext" | sed -e 's/\s([0-9][0-9]*)//'`?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that.  Juanito has given you a sed script that requires GNU sed, but you're using OSX which doesn't support class shortcuts like `\s`.  Use `sed -Ee 's/ \([0-9]+\)//'` instead.  Except ... don't.  :-)

Comment: A more portable alternative to this sed script would be `tr`.  Try this: `echo "file (1).ext" | tr -d ' ([:digit:])'`

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho - are you actually testing this somewhere?  Sed, by default, uses BRE unless you specify the `-E` option (in OSX) or `-r` option (GNU).  The `+` RE modifier is part of ERE, and not compatible with BRE.

Comment: Yes, I tested it on GNU sed without the -r option. Worked normally. The difference I see between '-r' and no '-r' for this regex is that the '+' and the parenthesis wouldn't need to be backslashed.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem, then.  According to the `re_format(7)` man page, in "basic" regular expressions, "*'+' and '?' are ordinary characters, and their functionality can be expressed using bounds ('{1,}' or '{0,1}' respectively).*  GNU sed obviously does not follow BRE rules to the letter.